# How to deal with two successive inserts in the same form (Order-OrderItem)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm simulating the process of selling items to customers. The seller can click on a button to create a new order. The Order form consists of a few fields for the Order itself and an empty grid with a footer row to add Order items.

**Table Order:**

```
OrderId
CreationDate
CreatedBy
```

**OrderItem**

```
OrderItemId
OrderItemQuantity
OrderId
```

In case of a new order, the system should insert a new row to the Orders Table and retrieve the new Id created by the system, then it would get the items created by the user in the New Order Form and insert it into the OrderItem table each with a reference to the OrderId.

Once the seller clicks on the button to create a new order, the form pops-ups and he should be able to add new items to the order right away. My problem is that he must save the order first with no items to get the OrderId then he should add the items in the grid.

This doesn't sound like the best way to do it, **I thought of a couple solutions**:

1- Once the seller clicks the button, I insert the Order into the Order Table and get the Id, and in the same way insert the items directly into the database once they're created. But the problem is I'm not sure how to distinguish if he closed the form without saving or with saving to know whether i should delete the records or not.

2- I thought of creating a datatable and insert the items temporarily into that table and when the seller clicks save, I would enter all these items into the database. But this would create so much extra code, but I don't mind if this is the best possible solution.

Does anyone have another suggestion ?

Comment: Go with option 1 but have a "completed" flag or similar. Set the flag to "true" when the order has been finished and you can then periodically clear down all uncompleted orders that are older than a certain age.

Comment: You should not do any saving at all until the user clicks OK, that way neither of this will be a problem. You will need to track the objects to insert until the user clicks OK.

Answer (score 0):

I went with option 2 as option 1 could lead to useless SQL operations.

I created an empty DataTable and saved it into a session. Each time the seller adds an item, I do the following:

1- Retrieve the DataTable from the session

2- Add a new row with the data to the Datatable

3- Save the DataTable to the session

4- Bind the Grid to the DataTable stored in the session